# Prove $f$ is identically zero in $\Omega = \{ z \in \Bbb C:|{\mathop{\rm Re}\nolimits} (z)| < 1,|{\mathop{\rm Im}\nolimits} (z)| < 1\} $

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega  = \{ z \in \Bbb C:|{\mathop{\rm Re}\nolimits} z| < 1,|{\mathop{\rm Im}\nolimits} z| < 1\} $ and consider the function $f:\bar\Omega\to\Bbb C$ continuous on $\bar\Omega$, analytic in $\Omega$, and with the property that $f(z)=0$ when $\rm{Re}(z) =1$. Prove that $f$ is identically zero in $\Omega$.

The following is a solution I copied from my prof's lecture note. I don't understand why $\text{Im}(F)=0$. Thank you!

> Let $F=f^2$ then $|F|=(\text{Re}f)^2-(\text{Im} f)^2+2(\text{Re}f)(\text{Im}f)$. $\text{Im} F =0$ for any $z\in \Omega$.
>   $|e^{-iF}|=e^{\text{Im} F}=1$, $e^{-iF}$ analytic on $\Omega$, then for any $z\in \overline\Omega$, $|e^{-iF}|=1$, then $\text{Im} f=0$ on $\Omega$, so $F$ is constant on $Omega$, then $f$ is constant on $\Omega$, then $f$ is identically zero.

---

P.S.

[image]

Comment: I can't understand the solution neither. It can be done by means of analytic continuation.

Comment: Please remove the photo and typeset its contents; it's not that hard.

Comment: @zhw. Just back from school. Someone helped with the edit :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different approach, hint: Consider $g(z) =f(z)f(iz)f(-z)f(-iz).$

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your hint. Using the hint, then $g(z)=0$ on the boundary of $\Omega$ and $g$ is analystic so $g=0$ on $\Omega$. I am really struggling on what to do next. How does that imply $f$ is identically zero? Thank you!

Comment: You have $g$ continuous on $\overline {\Omega},$ holomorphic on $\Omega,$ and $g =0$ on $\partial \Omega.$ That implies $g\equiv 0$ by max modulus thm. That in turn gives $f\equiv 0.$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't understand why g\equiv 0 implies f\equiv 0. Why it is not possible that $f(z),f(iz),f(-z),f(-iz)$ take turns to be zero?

Comment: If $f \not \equiv0$ then how many zeros can $f$ have in $\Omega?$

Comment: @Tony At least one of the four functions has infinitely many zeros in $\{ |\mathrm{Re}(z)|<1/2,  |\mathrm{Im}(z)|<1/2\}$. It is enough to show that the one function is identically zero.